# Idea cannot recognize a symbol even it is present in external dependencies

Tags: scala, intellij-idea, gradle, playframework

Does somebody understands what is a problem? Why my IDE doesn't see classes from dependencies? **Idea version: 17.2.2**

The root **build.gradle**:

```
subprojects.each {
    apply plugin: 'idea'
}
```

The root **setting.gradle**:

```
include 'client'
include 'api'

rootProject.name = 'app-1-akka-reactjs'
```

My **build.gradle** of **api** project:

```
apply plugin: 'play'

buildscript {
    repositories {
        jcenter()
    }

    dependencies {
        classpath 'org.iatoki:gradle-play-idea:0.4.1'
    }
}

apply plugin: 'org.iatoki.play-idea'

repositories {
    jcenter()
    ivy {
        url "https://repo.typesafe.com/typesafe/ivy-releases/"
        layout "pattern", {
            ivy "[organisation]/[module]/[revision]/ivys/ivy.xml"
            artifact "[organisation]/[module]/[revision]/jars/[artifact].[ext]"
        }
    }
}

model {
    components {
        play {
            platform play: '2.5.8', scala: '2.11', java: '1.8'
            injectedRoutesGenerator = true
        }
    }
}

dependencies {
    play 'com.typesafe.play:play-slick_2.11:2.1.0'
    play 'com.typesafe.play:play-slick-evolutions_2.11:2.1.0'

    play 'org.postgresql:postgresql:9.4-1200-jdbc41'
}
```

The **build.gradle** of **client** is empty for now.

To generate idea's files I've used:

```
gradle cleanIdea idea
```

[image: Here is how my project is look]

Comment: Here is project [github](https://github.com/sleshJdev/allneed.git) link

Comment: I have the same problem, even more it reproduces for all my team members. Looks like IDEA has some major bug with gradle dependencies

Comment: Hi, @Orest Kyrylchuk. You're right. I've answered about it on the JetBrains support [forum](https://intellij-support.jetbrains.com/hc/en-us/requests/1078123?flash_digest=1a54d3be6676f89b76eff2bfeae899e572b37b8c). It appears that such [bug](https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/SCL-12304) already is in their bug tracking system. Vote for that bug to track see any status updates.

Answer (score 0):

I faced a similar issue. I could resolve it by moving/copying the settings.xml file from $MVN_HOME/conf to ~/.m2 folder. As MVN_HOME was not detected by Idea it could not resolve the settings.xml from MVN_HOME.